# Workloads installed but not recognized by Visual Studio Mac

Tags: maui, visual-studio-mac

I regretfully ran Visual Studio Updates a few days ago, and following the update, I am stuck in a state that does not let me build or debug my .NET MAUI project.  When I launch Visual Studio, There is a message that says `The solution requires .NET SDK Workloads that are not currently installed`.  If I click on the Install button, I am asked for my root password but then there is no indication of progress, success, or failure.  My package console says the following:

```
Getting restore information for project /Users/adam/Projects/[redacted]/[redacted]/[redacted].csproj
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.312/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5) : error NETSDK1147: To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: maui-android
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
Unable to create package spec for project. '/Users/adam/Projects/[redacted]/[redacted]/[redacted].csproj'
```

Running `sudo dotnet workload restore` runs successfully but doesn't seem to change anything. If I run `dotnet workload list` in Terminal, I see the following:

```
Installed Workload Id      Manifest Version       Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------
maui-tizen                 8.0.3/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.100
maui-maccatalyst           8.0.3/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.100
maui-ios                   8.0.3/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.100
maui-android               8.0.3/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.100
ios                        17.0.8490/8.0.100      SDK 8.0.100
maui                       8.0.3/8.0.100          SDK 8.0.100
android                    34.0.52/8.0.100        SDK 8.0.100
```

I have tried closing Visual Studio, manually uninstalling each workload via `dotnet workload uninstall [workload id]`, restarting my machine, manually re-installing each workload, restarting my machine again, and opening Visual Studio again but I still see the same error.

### [image: Warning tooltip on Solution Explorer]

[image: Installed Workload List]

Comment: 'dotnet workload repair' also did not fix the problem

Comment: What are the target frameworks in your csproj?

Comment: **FYI** The latest Visual Stdio Mac does **not support** latest MAUI. [Visual Studio for Mac Retirement Announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/)

Comment: o_w net7.0-android and net7.0-ios

Comment: I think you need the .NET workloads installed for the .NET version you are targeting, from the dotnet workload list output you have 8.x workloads installed. Or you could try enabling .NET 8 support in VS Mac, in preferences - Other - Preview Features, check 'Use the .NET 8 SDK if installed' and restart VS Mac.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I was able to get things working by enabling the .NET 8 preview feature.  How would I specify the workload versions to install if I didn't want the latest?

Comment: Matt Ward, I Already did this but, getting error:
visual studio shows : The solution requires .NET SDK Workloads that are not currently installed, But it works fine If I create MAUI project by selecting .NET 7 version. but unable to run if created with .net 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled the .NET 8 preview feature as Matt Ward described in the comments and that fixed my problem.